# Integration of Guice into Dropwizard

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, guice, dropwizard, microservices

I want to integrate guice into my dropwizard application for dependency injection. For that i found these two github projects [dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice) and [dropwizard-guicey](https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey). I am not sure which one to use and what the advantages vs disadvantages (limitations) are. Did anyone already use one of those or tested both and could share his expierences? Maybe there is also another preferred way to integrate guice that i don't know of. It would be nice to share this as well. Thanks.

Comment: A user with your reputation could/should know that your question is clearly off-topic?!

Comment: Sorry for that. Is there a place where i can ask such questions?

Comment: At first, only dropwizard-guice existed. It was nice and clean. But it skipped dropwizard 0.9 entirely. And dropwizard 0.9 introduced significant changes that made dropwizard-guice incompatible with dropwizard. When dropwizard 1.0.0.0 alpha versions came, dropwizard-guicey came as a replacement to fill the void. Dropwizard-guice woke up very late, just right before dropwizard 1.0.0.0. And now we have two nice and active projects. So pick the one you want, they both integrate Guice appropriately (not enough in my personal view, but that's another topic).

Comment: I have been using dw-guicey for over a year now, have had no issue, great response time on requests and reliable and quick updates. I can highly recommend